# (discord.py) Detecting certain keywords in messages

Tags: discord.py

I was planning to make a grammar bot for fun, and I want it to find certain keywords inside a message, rather than just asking if it is ONLY that keyword. I haven't found anything close to what I want. Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want to check each message that is sent, you can check `message.content` in the `on_message` event for the keywords using normal Python. Example code below, where the code will check if FOO is in the message.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'FOO' in message.content:
        print('Keyword found in message')
        # Do stuff here
```